# Haskell: Can verbosity of converting from/to Integer be made more succinct?

Tags: haskell, types, type-conversion

I have the following piece of code in Haskell:

```
addm a b m = fromInteger $ mod (fromIntegral a + fromIntegral b) (fromIntegral m)
```

The idea is that, if the type of `a`, `b` and `m` doesn't have enough bits such that the addition could wrap (e.g. if using `Word8`), then the calculation would be incorrect. So, to prevent this, we convert temporarily to `Integer`, do the calculation and then convert back.

Is there a more succinct way to write this without the three `fromIntegral` and one `fromInteger` ?

Comment: You can shorten the name of `fromIntegrak`, you can make a ho function that encapsulates all the conversions, ...

Comment: But what do you *really* want? Can you describe what all this manipulation is for? Why is overflow actually bad in this context?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [augustuss's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624758/haskell-can-verbosity-of-converting-from-to-integer-be-made-more-succinct#comment43670155_27624758):

```
addm a b m = i $ mod (i a + i b) (i m)
  where i = fromIntegral
```

(`fromInteger` and `fromIntegral` work identically on `Integer`s, so we can replace `fromInteger` with `fromIntegral`).

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you should use `toInteger` and `fromInteger`, since `fromIntegral` will convert to `Num`, not `Integer`.  Unfortunately there isn't a particularly friendly way to do it, but with a few combinators you can make it shorter:

```
import Data.Function (on)

addm a b m = fromInteger $ flip mod (toInteger m) $ on (+) toInteger a b
```

But with the operator

```
infixr 9 .:
(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
(.:) = (.).(.)
```

you can define it as (if you make `m` the first argument)

```
addm m = fromInteger .: flip mod (toInteger m) .: on (+) toInteger
```

But at this point it's somewhat difficult to make it more pointfree without making it unreadable.  Casting in Haskell is always explicit, you can't get around it.  Some of the names simply make it a bit verbose, but you gain type safety from it.  Personally, I would probably instead define two versions of this function, one specific to `Integer` and the other generalized to `Integral`:

```
addm :: Integral a => a -> a -> a -> a
addm a b m = fromInteger $ addmInteger (toInteger a) (toInteger b) (toInteger m)
    where
        addmInteger :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
        addmInteger a' b' m' = (a' + b') `mod` m'
```

While this is more typing, it cleanly separates the logic from the type casting.  You could shorten this with a combinator similar to `on`:

```
addm :: Integral a => a -> a -> a -> a
addm a b m = fromInteger $ on3 addmInteger toInteger a b m
    where
        on3 :: (b -> b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> a -> c
        on3 f g x y z = f (g x) (g y) (g z)
        addmInteger :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
        addmInteger a' b' m' = (a' + b') `mod` m'
```

Although this is more total code.  I personally still like it better because `on3` could be used elsewhere easily, and the business logic is still separated from the casting.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to define

```
addm a b m = fromInteger $
   (fromIntegral a + fromIntegral b) `mod` (fromIntegral m)
```

But what do you *really* want?

Based on the description, I will assume that the *inputs* are the same type as the *output*. I will also assume that the type involved is sufficiently well-behaved—that overflow wraps around nicely modulo `k`, for some `k`. This is the case for `Word8` (`k = 2^8`), `Int8` (`k = 2^8`), etc., and in GHC is also the case for `Word` and `Int`. So what am I getting at here?

For some `q` and some `r` such that `0<=r<m`,

```
a + b - q * m = r
```

This is the essential concept of Euclidean division (`divMod` is a little weird and doesn't implement that exactly, but it's pretty close). But then

```
a' + b' - q' * m' ≡ r' (mod k)
```

for *any* `a'`, `b'`, `q'`, and `m'` congruent to `a`, `b`, `q`, and `m` modulo `k`. This strongly suggests that overflow won't really be a problem once you've clarified the actual purpose of your calculation.